# OnKeyPress only when Enter and Not Blank

Tags: javascript

HTML Element

```
<textarea placeholder="Chat with me" ref="chatInput" onKeyPress={this.handleSendMessage}></textarea>
```

JS Handler

```
handleSendMessage: function(event){
    var data = this.refs.chatInput.getDOMNode().value;
    if(event.keyCode == 13 && data.length > 1){
      //sendMessage....
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 13 && data.length == 1) {
      //isEmpty so do nothing
    }
  }
```

I have an input field and I want to send a message only when ENTER is pressed and textarea is NOT BLANK. In case text area is blank I want to do nothing...so the input field will remain empty with the place holder. I have omitted the rest of the code as I deemed it irrelevant to what I am trying to achieve. I will add any additional code on request.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Message doesn't get sent when I type for example "Hello", when I hit enter it breaks to new line.

Comment: @ilyamilosevic That is what I thought too, but when you hit "enter" that is counted as a char too.

Comment: probably call ` event.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the function ?

Comment: Ok I switched from onkeypress to onkeyup. Now messages do get sent, and blank messages dont get sent. Only problem is when enter is fired, the placeholder clears ... as if something will happen... then my else statement clears the input and the placeholder reappears. When enter is hit and input is empty NOTHING should happen.

Comment: have you checked `data.length`? what it shows?

Comment: When it is empty it shows 1

Comment: Which means, it have a space. try using trim. For example, `<textarea> </textarea>` and `<textarea></textarea>` are not same. See the space

Answer (score 0):

```
handleSendMessage: function(event){
    var data = this.refs.chatInput.getDOMNode().value;
    if(event.keyCode == 13 && data.length > 1){
      //sendMessage....
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 13 && data.length == 1) {
      //isEmpty so do nothing
      return false;
    }
  }
```

`return false;` should do the trick